# Apache tomcat cannot find vaadin apps

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, vaadin

##### Hello there,

I am making a web server as a school project. The primary objective here is to make a web server such that my friends and I can deploy their vaadin projects on the internet.

I decided for to use Apache tomcat for the localhost server and ngrok to tunnel it to the internet. The tomcat server works fine but when I make my own app through vaadin or just using the ones provided to me I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAL0l.png).

---

##### This is my log for the day

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:26:16 -0500] GET / HTTP/1.1 200 11243
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:26:17 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1 404 795
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:26:17 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120.png HTTP/1.1 404 783
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:26:17 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1 404 787
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:26:17 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1 404 775
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:26:17 -0500] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 200 21630
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:09:35:55 -0500] GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:05 -0500] GET / HTTP/1.1 200 11243
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:06 -0500] GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:06 -0500] GET /tomcat.svg HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:06 -0500] GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:06 -0500] GET /asf-logo-wide.svg HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:06 -0500] GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:06 -0500] GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:15 -0500] GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1 401 2499
127.0.0.1 - manager [15/Nov/2022:11:02:33 -0500] GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1 200 19900
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:33 -0500] GET /manager/css/manager.css HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:33 -0500] GET /manager/images/tomcat.svg HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:33 -0500] GET /manager/images/asf-logo.svg HTTP/1.1 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:02:51 -0500] GET /icsprojects-version-1.0/ HTTP/1.1 404 783
127.0.0.1 - manager [15/Nov/2022:11:03:26 -0500] GET /manager/html HTTP/1.1 200 18316
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:18:00 -0500] GET /icsprojects-version-1.0/ HTTP/1.1 404 783
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:22:16 -0500] GET / HTTP/1.1 200 11243
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:22:20 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1 404 795
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:22:21 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon-120x120.png HTTP/1.1 404 783
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:22:21 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png HTTP/1.1 404 787
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:22:24 -0500] GET /apple-touch-icon.png HTTP/1.1 404 775
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2022:11:22:24 -0500] GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1 200 21630
```

---

###### Here is what I have tried

1. Deploying my own vaadin apps
2. Deploying other peoples vaadin apps
3. Making sure that the app was packaged into a war file
4. Tried with gradle and maven
5. Extensively reviewed the pom.xml and build.gradle files

Comment: What is the catalina.log (or catalina.log) telling you? Probably some error on deployment... (BTW: What tomcat version did you use? Tomcat 10 is not supported with vaadin 23.x)

Comment: I have used spring boot and normal packaging and I have also tried tomcat 8,9 and 10. I don't have access to the machine right now but I will put the log when I am able to use it

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you use Tomcat 10? Vaadin currently only supports Tomcat up to 9 because auf the javax -> jakarta packages changes.

Also for a school project it is simpler to just use the default sprint boot packaging with an embedded webserver.

Comment: Nah, I have tried spring boot and normal. I also tried different tomcat versions. I have also replaced javax with jakarta in maven plugins. Also I am not sure what kind of setup my classmates are going to use so this needs to be as flexible as possible